# EJS and node not loading template correctly, res.render

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

In one of my node files, i have a function executing for every page(simple login implementation). In the code below a chatbar will only show up for a specific route. My flow for the page is this:

-Client logs in...hits '/', and runs the below function. showChatBar = 
false.
-immediately the page then redirects to '/chat' route. showChatBar = true. This should be displaying the chat bar now. However it is not.

My thoughts, are that...this happens so fast that the showChatBar=true, never gets to load. Maybe an async problem? Maybe something with the res.render?

here is my node.js code

```
exports.login = function (req, res) {
var showChatBar = false, navButton = '', navTitle='',navSubTitle='';

if(typeof req.url !='undefined'){
    if(req.url.indexOf('chat')!=-1){
        //Consumer View
        showChatBar = true;
        navButton = "close";
    }

    if(req.url.indexOf('agent')!=-1){
        //Agent View
        navButton = "close";
        navTitle='My Clients';
    }
}

if(typeof req.headers.referer != 'undefined'){
    if(req.headers.referer.indexOf('agent')!=-1){
        //Agent Chat View
        navButton = "back";
    }
}

res.render('index', {title: 'Express', showChatBar: showChatBar, navButton:navButton, navTitle:navTitle,navSubTitle:navSubTitle});
```

};

Here is the EJS portion:

```
<script>
    var chatBar =<%= showChatBar %>, navButton='<%= navButton %>', navTitle='<%= navTitle %>',navSubTitle='<%= navSubTitle %>'; 
</script>
```

Thoughts on why this is not updating the template correctly with showChatBar = true?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `req.originalUrl` instead of `req.url`

Here's some documentation about it:

> [req.originalUrl](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#req.originalUrl)
>
> *`req.url` is not a native Express property, it is inherited from Node’s http module.,*
>
> This property is much like `req.url`; however, it retains the original request URL, allowing you to rewrite req.url freely for internal routing purposes. For example, the “mounting” feature of app.use() will rewrite `req.url` to strip the mount point.
>
> `// GET /search?q=something
>   req.originalUrl
>   // => "/search?q=something"`

Comment: It appears that when the rerouting happens, it doesn't want to reload the index.js again...only keeping the first showChatBar value...